# Porting HTC sense 4 accordion effect on android?

Tags: android, htcsense

hope you might have noticed the accordion effect in sense 4 at the end of list in htc sense 4 rom.

[image: sense 4 end of list effect]

Is there an existing port of this effect to normal android or cyanogen?

Is it possible? If so, which framework file is responsible for this one? Does HTC do this in there own framework or in android framework?? Is it possible to replace the glow effect in android with any other?